# How to display an xml file with microsoft schemas?

Tags: xml, wordpress, file

I want to display an xml file on a web page. What's the best way to do it on a Wordpress platform?
The code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NEWSITEM xmlns:usr="urn:the-xml-files:xslt" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <ARTICLEID>9502</ARTICLEID>
    <DATELINE>2013-02-15</DATELINE>
    <HEADLINE>Fixed broadband quarterly metrics 3Q 2012</HEADLINE>
    <AUTHOR>Martin Scott</AUTHOR>
    <DATEAUTHORED>2013-02-14</DATEAUTHORED>
    <SUMMARY>The fixed broadband market continues to grow apace. Emerging markets are buoying overall market growth, while developed markets continue to be dynamic at the operator and access technology level. Our quarterly metrics include market share, access technology splits and quarterly growth figures for 59 countries, and have been updated to include 3Q 2012 data.</SUMMARY>
    <COPYRIGHTLINE>Copyright Analysys Mason 2013</COPYRIGHTLINE>
    <SOURCE>Analysys Mason (http://www.analysysmason.com/Research/)</SOURCE>
    <FILES>Analysys_Mason_Fixed_broadband_quarterly_metrics_3Q2012_RDMB0.xls</FILES>
    <KEYWORDS>Analysys, Mason, AnalysysMason, Analysys Mason, amData, amBroadband, amFBroadband, Fixed Broadband, , Fixed, broadband, quarterly, metrics, 3Q, 2012, The, fixed, broadband, market, continues, to, grow, apace, Emerging, markets, are, buoying, overall, market, growth, while, developed, markets, continue, to, be, dynamic, at, the, operator, and, access, technology, level, Our, quarterly, metrics, include, market, share, access, technology, splits, and, quarterly, growth, figures, for, 59, countries, and, have, been, updated, to, include, 3Q, 2012, data, </KEYWORDS>
</NEWSITEM>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please describe what the actual problem is that you are facing?

Comment: More details please. Is that sort of XML going to be the entered content of a page? A post? Is it supposed to come from somewhere other than page/post content?

Comment: Hi sorry guys. I want to add a feed from an ftp account. It's new to me and I thought I'd ask to see if anyone knows how to add one. I found some information at: http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1649. So to surmise, the issue I was facing was trying to add a feed from an ftp account to show the latest documents that are added into the ftp account on a wordpress page.